# Randomly sampling data in Denodo

Tags: random, sample, denodo

I wonder what is analog of SQL SERVER newid() command in Denodo (VQL)? My ultimate goal is to randomly sample data in Denodo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the encrypt function, as it provides a guid for a value, it generates different values for same input.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a random sample of a query by combining a LIMIT command with RAND()...

```
SELECT *, RAND() AS rnd
FROM table
ORDER BY rnd
LIMIT 100;
```